# Changing variable of javascript object (this.variable) not working

Tags: javascript

Im trying to understand javascript objects but I got stuck on a problem.
Why is this variable returning "NaN"?

```
function Game(){

    this.players = 0;
    this.round = 0;
    this.turn = this.round / this.players;

}

var game = new Game();
game.players = 5;
game.round = 10;

console.log(game.turn);
```

game.turn should be 2 not NaN.

The problem is that "this.players" and "this.round" is not changing and since you cant divide by 0 it returns NaN.

I rewrote it and surprisingly this worked.

```
function Game(){

    this.players = 0;
    this.round = 0;

    this.turn = function(){

        return this.round / this.players;

    }

}
var game = new Game();
game.players = 5;
game.round = 10;

console.log(game.turn());
```

**Why does the second part of code work but not the first?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach evaluates the statement `this.turn = this.round / this.players;` when the `Game` function is called. You call it before you change the values of `players` and `round`.

The second approach evaluates the statement `return this.round / this.players;` when the `turn` function is called, which is after you set those values.

For the first approach to work, you'd need to use a getter or setter to calculate the value of `turn` either when it is got or when one of the other values is set.

```
function Game() {

    this.players = 0;
    this.round = 0;
}


Object.defineProperty(Game.prototype, "turn", {
    get: function get_turn() {
        return this.round / this.players;;
    }
});


var game = new Game();
game.players = 5;
game.round = 10;
console.log(game.turn);
```

Comment: Might be worth elaborating on initialisation a bit, as your answer explains what is returned when, but the questions asks why.

Comment: Every answer was great. But I'm going to accept this one since he also gave an example on how to make the first code snippet work. (I know I didn't ask for it but I learned something new other than the question.)

Answer (score 2):

Because the first snippet is running on initialization, so changing the values after instantiation is not going to change the value of `turn`.

In your second example, you are computing `turn` on demand, so its only calculated when you invoke the function and you are invoking the function after you've set the values of `players` and `round`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code sample you posted, you are directly assigning the value of `'turn.`' It is never recomputed merely for your having assigned different values to '`players`' and '`round`'.

In your second version, you have written a `function` that is `invoked` *each time* `turn()` is called that *recomputes* the value based on the *current* values of `players` and `round`.